# turn off password protected file sharing in Windows server 2016,option at advanced sharing settings is no longer available

Tags: password-protection, windows-server-2016

The issues is as follows, I have a couple of services running  that need to copy files from server A to server B, server A being Windows server 2012 R2, server B being Windows server 2016, services are not capable to send credentials or impersonate logged users and apparently the option "Turn off password protected file sharing" is no longer available in Windows server 2016.
- server are all into a LAN no internet facing, so turning off password is not a security issue.
- No, I did not code the services and I don't have access to code to enable sending user and password. I'm only responsible for setting up the communications.
- guess profile is enabled in the local security profiles
- both folders (origin and destination) are shared with 'Everyone' for read and write.
Does anyone knows how can I remove the password request for shared folders?

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered this same problem, the following helped me:

This may be due to user name conflicts
(ie.) The SharedMachine and ClientMachine**s** have **Same UserNames**

So Make sure the **SharedMachine's** UserName does not match the **ClientMachine** UserName.

> Since there is going to be many ClientMachines, Its hard to rename
> them all,
>
> so Rename the SharedMachine's UserAccounts:
>
> -> In the SharedMachine GoTo: **AdministrativeTools -> ComputerManagement -> UsersAndGroups**
>
> -> **Rename all the available user Accounts**

eg:

> -> Rename the **Administrator**" Account to **SOME_NAME_1**
>
> -> Rename the **Guest**" Account to **SOME_NAME_2**
>
> -> **Finally, restart the SharedMachine.**

Comment: Exactly my problem. I have the same username on my Linux machine as on Windows machine and it wasn't allowing me to connect. Is there another way except renaming the user?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you already found a solution but if not here is some good information. THe turn off password protect sharing option has moved slightly. It is now under "All Networks" instead of the current profile

[image]

But in server 2016 enabling this might not be the fix you need. I found this other [stack overflow question](https://serverfault.com/questions/682086/how-can-i-get-windows-server-2012-r2-to-stop-asking-for-a-file-share-password) and this was important. If the users are in a different domain they must enter the username as "Guest" This was the true fix for me since the share was under domain:local, no other remote user is in the same local domain, and must use the guest account. They still don't need a password, which is nice

Lastly, if none of that works I found this great post: https://www.kapilarya.com/how-to-turn-off-password-protected-sharing-in-windows-10 In addition to what you've done with sharing and permissions they have two registry settings

- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa **everyoneincludeanonymous** set to 1
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters **restrictnullsessaccess** set to 0

Comment: thanks we have to eventually ask the developer to modify the service to send credentials but this is a good one for later implementations.